# TinyMCE 4.5 Help button ? - what is the expected behavior

Tags: tinymce-4

I have a help button in TinyMCE 4. When I click on the button nothing happens. In 3.1.2 I would get /iw/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/about.htm coming up.

I guess I did not find the proper documentation on how to implement this button in version 4. I tried to find in the TinyMCE docs and in threads here. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong in my Fiddle?

```
     tinymce.init({
       selector: 'textarea',
       height: 500,
       theme: 'modern',
       plugins: [
          'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
          'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
          'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
          'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern  imagetools codesample toc'
          ],
          toolbar1: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
          toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | codesample | help',
         image_advtab: true,
         templates: [
            { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
                 { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
            ],
            content_css: [
                '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
                '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
            ],
            setup: function (editor) {
                 editor.on('load', function(e){
                 console.log('start debugging');
            });
        }
       });
```

I have a TinyMCE 4.5 widget in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytr2avwz/12/)

Answer (score 0):

This function was removed from TinyMCE 4 - the fact that adding the button to the toolbar still makes a button show up is likely an oversight/defect in TinyMCE 4.x.

In my brief testing the help button has been non-functional in all releases of TinyMCE 4 back to 4.0.

If you want that button to function I would open a request on the TinyMCE GitHub:

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues